# Making multiple output lists into one list (python)

Tags: python

I have this generator

```
def keys():
    objects = [{'1':True,'2':True,'3':False,'4':False,'5':True,'6':True}]
    rng = range(len(objects))
    clean = int(''.join(map(str, rng)))
    for keys, values in objects[clean].iteritems():
        if values == True:
            yield keys
```

and then i want to get all the generator values, which I do using for loop

```
for i in keys():
    i= i.split()
    print i
```

and the output is :

```
['1']
['2']
['5']
['6']
```

is there a way I can add them to a single list?
like [['1'],['2'],['5'],['6']] or most preferably ['1','2','5','6'].
Would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Yes... `your_list = list(keys())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just convert it to a list directly, as `list` takes an iterable;

```
out = list(keys())
```

Or if you want to, you could use a list comprehension;

```
out = [key for key in keys()]
```

This would make it easier to filter out certain items from the generator  using the `[for x in y if z]` syntax.

Both output;

```
>>> print(out)
['2', '6', '1', '5']
```

Comment: actually it sorts as well, thank you ! I completely ignored the list comprehension, thanks a big time!!

Comment: I updated my answer mere seconds before you commented that to make that clear, but thanks @AChampion :)

Comment: `[key for key in keys()]` is just overkill.

Comment: I agree @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but it's nice to know that it's a possibility, as a common use case would be to filter out certain items yielded from the generator, and that is more easily done with the list comprehension so may be more favourable for other people reading this question.

Answer (score -1):

Like this?:

```
my_list = []
for i in keys():
    my_list.append(i.split())

print my_list
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be a list comprehension like this if you want it as similar as possible to your original answer:

```
list = [key.split() for key in keys()]
print(list)
```